# Как заменить элемент в массиве?

Tags: ios, swift, apple, uikit, foundation

Есть массив. Есть элемент. Есть элемент на который будем заменять. Есть ли метод типа названиемассив.replaceElement(oldElement, newElement). Если нет, то как лучше реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Через экстеншен почему-то у меня не получилось, а так было бы именно то, что Вы хотите. Поэтому вот функция, правда только для String:

```
func replaceElement(in array: inout [String], element old: String, with new: String) {
  if let i = array.firstIndex(of: old) {
    array[i] = new
  }
}
```

Пример:

```
var people = ["Ivy", "Jordell", "Liam", "Maxime", "Shakia"]
replaceElement(in: &people, element: "Maxime", with: "Max")
print(people)
```

Answer (score 1):

В идеале oldElement должен реализовывать протокол `Equatable`, чтобы мы могли найти его в массиве.

Но я написал вариант, где это не обязательно. На простых типах работает. На более сложных не пробывал.

```
extension Array {

    @discardableResult
    mutating func replaceElement(_ oldElement: Element, withElement element: Element) -> Bool {
        if let i = firstIndex(where: { String(describing: $0) == String(describing: oldElement) }) {
            self[i] = element
            return true
        }
        return false
    }

}
```

Функция возвращает `true`, если успешно нашли и заменили элемент, иначе `false`.

Пример:

```
var a: [Any] = ["a", 1]
a.replaceElement(1, withElement: "4")
print(a)
```

Вывод: `["a", "4"]`